# Will returning an object call its destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, return, destructor

I have a very simple class which handles callbacks.  A caller asks for a Callback from a Manager.  So long as the Callback object is held by the caller, it remains valid.  Once the object dies however, it's destructor sets a pointer inside the Manager to NULL so it knows to throw it away when it next encounters it.

... or at least, that's the basic idea I'm after.

```
class Manager{
public:
    void executeOnList() { ... }

    Callback requestCallback(Drawable * target){
          Drawable ** ptr = list.add(target);
          return Callback(ptr);  // <-- the point of interest
    }
private:
    List list;
};


class Callback{
    friend Manager;
private:
    Callback(Drawable ** targetPtr){
        drawablePtr = targetPtr;
    }
public:
    ~Callback(){
        (*drawablePtr) = NULL;  // <-- dtor of interest
    }
private:
    Drawable ** drawablePtr;
};
```

My question is, will that `Manager::requestCallback()` call the destructor of `Callback` before returning the structure to it's caller?

If that is the case, would there be any way to prevent this, while (more or less) maintaining the basic idea behind `Callback`'s functionality?

Comment: It depends in whether you get [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) or not. In your example, I expect you would.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I've read of that, though it seems risky without anyway to explicitly ask for it...

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it (well, with some compilers you can switch it off, but that would seem like a pessimization). You should not rely on RVO *not* taking place.

Comment: But there is nothing to worry about either: if a copy is elided, it means there is one less construction, as well as one less destruction.

Comment: @juanchopanza - The destructor though, zeroes out state in the Manager, so calling it once or many times has the same effect.  RVO seems easy enough to ensure, but I wonder if it'd be valid with debug builds too.  I made an edit using the idea you mentioned though about matching constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object which is on the stack gets destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. That is, conceptually, the temporary object will get out of scope when it is returned from a function. That said, when returning an object copying it may be elided by the compiler, in which case the temporary object in the return statement doesn't seem to exist at all. However, if copy elision takes place or not is an optimization and not guaranteed.

Solely depending on the destructor doesn't seem to work in your case. However, what may work is to distinguish between temporary objects being passed around and objects being held (named or pointed to). The basic idea would be to consider the pointed to pointer a resource which is owned by an object and resetting it only when the actual owner is destroyed (similar to `std::unique_ptr<T>`) or when all owners are destroyed (similar to `std::shared_ptr<T>`). Assuming you can use r-value references, you can get both forms right, otherwise you can only get the shared ownership right.

Here is a brief outline of how the single ownership logic could look like:

```
class Callback{
    friend Manager;
private:
    Callback(Drawable ** targetPtr){
        drawablePtr = targetPtr;
    }
public:
    Callback(Callback&& other):
        drawablePtr(other.drawablePtr) {
        other.drawablePtr = 0;
    }
    ~Callback(){
        if (drawablePtr) {
            (*drawablePtr) = 0;
        }
    }
private:
    Drawable ** drawablePtr;
};
```

If you can't use r-value semantics you could still use the same logic, actually, but there is a risk that the "resource" is accidentally stolen by from a named object when a copy is created. Using a move constructor avoids this risk.

Comment: Oh, that's clever.  I had to re-read the copy constructor a few times before the logic behind it sunk in.  That will work beautifully, thank you!

Comment: @Clairvoire: Note that the "copy constructor" is actually a _move constructor_. It would work using a copy constructor, too, although with somewhat unusual and dangerous semantics which is why I used the move constructor where stealing the resource is normal.

Answer (score 2):

You may add a move constructor (c++11) or a copy destructor:

```
class Callback{
    friend Manager;
private:
    explicit Callback(Drawable** targetPtr) : drawablePtr(targetPtr) {}
    // C++11
    Callback(Callback&& rhs) : drawablePtr(rhs.drawablePtr) { rhs.drawablePtr = NULL; }
    // else
    Callback(Callback& rhs) : drawablePtr(rhs.drawablePtr) { rhs.drawablePtr = NULL; }
public:
    ~Callback(){
        if (drawablePtr) { (*drawablePtr) = NULL; }
    }
private:
    Drawable ** drawablePtr;
};
```

Comment: I totally forgot to check the pointer-pointer's validity, nice catch on that!  I'm using VS2010 which is showing it's age now that C++11 is out.  Maybe I'll get lucky and it'll have move constructors anyway

Answer (score 0):

all right, the temporary Callback object will be destroyed after requestCallback returns, which will lead to Drawable * set to NULL, and the copied Callback object don't work either.

Move does work, but it is not the only solution. in fact, this is just like auto-ptr in c++98, just steal the resource from one , into another.